# Show/Hide Labels - Adding and Removing vs Setting Visible in GWT

Tags: gwt, visibility, widget, show-hide, label

I suppose this could be a general javascript question, but I have a widget that, by default, has a label.  I need a way to have a label-less widget.  I currently have a special constructor with a boolean indicating whether or not to show this label.

Instead, if I were to add a method to show/hide this label, would it be better use visibility in CSS, or add/remove the label from its parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS visibility.

However, if you are using GWT and its other cohorts (smartgwt, gxt), setVisible(boolean), show(), hide() is already crafted into their visual components.

When introducing new visual components, you should simply extend the Widget class or any of its subclasses, in order to make full use of GWT features for your new component. The heavy weight of a GWT class Java features is already segregated by the GWT compiler as fixed costs in javascript code - so you might as well extend the Widget class.

And why would you not use the already existent Label class found in GWT (or smartgwt or gxt) and then use the setVisible (or show() hide()) property methods?

Comment: Thanks.

In my original question, I had assumed that the setVisible() method used the visibility property, but it uses the display property.  I think your answer still holds, just use setVisible(), not add/remove  widget.

Comment: Not working both the methods. `setVisible()` and `show()` / `hide()`. I have used the methods for `TextField` component of GWT extjs. both methods don't work for me.

Comment: Are you sure extjs TextField inherits Widget? And is that Widget class Google's Widget class or but a class with the same name?

Comment: TextField -> Field -> BoxComponent -> Component -> Widget. Ultimately it inherits from `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget`. But still it does not have this functions working for `setVisible()` and `show() / hide()`.